# RJython send Mail via .bat Firewall

Tags: r, email, batch-file, jython

We have .bat Files which call an R-script and generate some data and then send an email to certain users via rJython.

If I run this script in RStudio everything goes well and the mail is sent. But if i call the .bat file we get the following error.

It has probably something to do with the firewall in our company, can somebody help us out? We need to tell our IT departement something bc they cant help us either.

```
Error in jython.exec(rJython,mail): (-1, 'Unmapped exception:java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect') Execution halted
```

The R-Code to send the mail is:

```
#Sendmail Code
rJython<-rJython()
rJython$exec("import smtplib")
rJython$exec("from email.MIMEText import MIMEText")
rJython$exec("import email.utils")
rJython$exec("COMMASPACE = ', '")

recipients_string_j = paste("toaddrs  = [",recipients_string,"]",sep="")

#mail config
mail<-c( fromaddr = 'test@XXX.com", 
  recipients_string_j, 
  paste("msg = MIMEText('",data.frame,"','html')",sep="",collapse=""),
  paste("msg['Subject'] = 'DUMMY SUBJECT'"),
  "msg['From'] = fromaddr",
  "msg['To']= COMMASPACE.join(toaddrs)",
  "server = smtplib.SMTP('00.00.00.000')", 
  "server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg.as_string())", 
  "server.quit()") 


#send mail
jython.exec(rJython,mail)
```

Comment: Networking problem, unrelated to SO. (what's this IP for a mail server ???)

Comment: A Dummy IP bc I dont know if my IT Department likes it if i post their IP here.

Comment: In this case use 192.168.0.1 or X.X.X.X, 0.0.0.0 is the default route and is unusable as an IP and looks like a possible source of error. (But routing can be the error if you're not launching the script from the same machine)

Comment: OK thx. But the IP cant be the problem here bc from within R we have no problems. It has something todo with the fact that  we cant execute .exe files, but I cant find an .exe in the package..

Comment: I assume you're under windows, maybe this has to do with the content of the .bat file (how you execute this python in java in R...)

Comment: (And so I wonder why on earth you don't run it as python script directly instead of this nested envs)

Comment: yeah we use windows. We dont have python only R so the only way to do it is to use this workaround.

Comment: Why not sending the mail directly in R in this case ? But that's out of scope for the question.